# MySQL Analyze and Optimize - Are they required if only inserts - and the table has no joins?

Tags: mysql, insert, indexing, myisam

I have a MyISAM table in MySQL which consists of two fields (f1 integer unsigned, f2 integer unsigned) and contains 320 million rows. I have an index on f2. Every week I insert about 150,000 rows into this table. I would like to know what is the frequency with which I need to run "analyze" and "optimize" on this table (as it would probably take a long time and block in the meantime)? I do not do any deletes or update statements, but just insert new rows every week. Also, I am not using this table in any joins so, based on this information, are "analyze" and "optimize" really required?

Thanks in advance,
Tim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ANALYZE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/analyze-table.html) checks the keys, [`OPTIMIZE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimize-table.html) kind of reorganizes tables.

If you never...ever... delete or update the data in your table, only insert new ones, you won't need analyze or optimize.

Comment: Thanks a lot...I had previously thought that they had to be run fairly frequently on any table...so thanks :)